# In AWS API Gateway, How do I include a stage parameter as part of the event variable in Lambda (Node)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a stage variable set up called "environment".

I would like to pass it through in a `POST` request as part of the JSON.

Example:

Stage Variables

- environment : "development"

JSON

```
{
  "name": "Toli",
  "company": "SomeCompany"
}
```

`event` variable should look like;

```
{
  "name": "Toli",
  "company": "SomeCompany",
  "environment": "development"
}
```

So far the best I could come up with was the following mapping template (under Integration Request):

```
{
    "body" : $input.json('$'),
    "environment" : "$stageVariables.environment"
}
```

Then in node I do

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var environment = event.environment;
    // hack to merge stage and JSON
    event = _.extend(event.body, {
      environment : environment
    });
    ....
```

Comment: That seems to be the official way to do it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/amazon-api-gateway-using-stage-variables.html

Answer (score 5):

If your API  Gateway method use *Lambda Proxy integration*, all your stage variables will be available via the `event.stageVariables` object.

For the project I'm currently working on, I created a simple function that goes over all the properties in `event.stageVariables` and appends them to `process.env` (e.g.: `Object.assign(process.env, event.stageVariables);`)

Comment: while trivial, this great answer was very challenging to come by.. 10x

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion of using a mapping template to pass-through the variable would be the recommended solution for this type of workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the stage name in the `$context` object.

Integration Request:

```
{
    "environment" : "$context.stage"
}
```